# PHP, see how your function is called

Tags: php, function

Is there a way you can see inside a PHP function how it is activated? As a statement or as a function?

```
foo();
$bar = foo();
```

Inside the function foo() I want to know which of above 2 ways was used.

Comment: Short answer? No. Long answer? No, so far as PHP is aware, they're both called the same way.

Comment: It might also help to explain your use case/what you're trying to achieve by knowing if a function is called expecting a return value or not.

Comment: You could use http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php and then have an array of lines and types in an array and then check which line it was called from and then compare that in the array? Its a bit long winded though.

Comment: If you want to know whether calling code is saving the result _after_ the function is executed, it is impossible unless you are able to see into the future.

Comment: Assuming you're wanting to know whether to `echo` or `return` in the function, many functions including PHP built-ins use a passed parameter `true` to `return`.  See `var_export()`, `print_r()` etc...  But easiest would be to `return` and when needed `echo foo();`

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong question, what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Put a parameter in the function, define a constant before the call, use a wrapper (fooFct will be foo, etc)....

Answer (score 0):

This code should help you.

```
<?php

function foo() {

    $debugStackTraceArray = debug_backtrace();
    $debugStackTraceFunctionArray = null;
    $calledMethod = null;

    foreach($debugStackTraceArray as $key => $value) {

        if (__FUNCTION__ == $value['function']) {

            $debugStackTraceFunctionArray = $value;
            break;
        }   
    }

    if ($debugStackTraceFunctionArray != null) {

        $fileArray = file($debugStackTraceFunctionArray['file']);       
        $line = $fileArray[$debugStackTraceFunctionArray['line'] - 1];

        if (strpos($line, '=') === false)                                   
            $calledMethod = 'function';
        else        
            $calledMethod = 'statement';

        if ($calledMethod != null)
            var_dump($calledMethod);
    }

    return 'return';
}

foo();
$foo = foo();

?>
```

Output

```
string(9) "statement" string(8) "function"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I get the idea, is indeed usefull

The source line in your example is one off, the file() function puts the first line in [0]

Comment: Indeed $line = `$fileArray[$debugStackTraceFunctionArray['line']];` needs to be `$line = $fileArray[$debugStackTraceFunctionArray['line'] - 1];`

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: No, so far as PHP is aware, they're both called the same way.

You can get a Trace by throwing a exception or using [debug-backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php), to debug where the function is called.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks all for the feedback. It is indeed possible to use the debug_backtrace() function for this. I'm now using below construction.

```
<?php

function foo() {

    $stack = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS, 1);

    $file = file($stack[0]['file']); 
    $line = trim($file[$stack[0]['line']-1]);

    if ( substr($line, 0, strlen(__FUNCTION__)) == __FUNCTION__ )
      $statement = TRUE;
    else 
      $statement = FALSE;

}

foo();
$foo = foo();

?>
```

Comment: And what in the world is this useful for? O_o Also note that there are any number of ways in which this will break trivially.

Comment: Just as example... `array_walk($array, 'foo')` – now what?